# How to implement the communication between Thread and AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am developing an application using Android SDK. In this application I am facing a problem when an `Activity` starts a `Thread`.  The new `Thread` starts an  `AsyncTask`, but the `Thread`  has to wait for completion of the `AsyncTask` execution.

Is it possible to start `AsyncTask` in a thread, and if so, how should it be implement?
Please can anyone share your experience with me about this kind of tasks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just say thread to sleep for some times and then check a variable again like this
in below code someValue was setted in asynctask postExecute method

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!someValue) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch {
                Log.i("LOG", "ERROR");
            }
        }
        Log.i("LOG", "Async Task Finished");
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Aaarrghh!! A sleep loop to detect if an async task has finished!  NO! Stop it!

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not create an AsyncTask from a thread other than main thread.
2. If you should wait anyway, why create AsyncTask? perform it on the thread.